# Android AltBeacon Advertise Power and Visibility Range

Tags: android, altbeacon

The Android AltBeacon Library and Android Beacon API provides option to set the advertise power to advertise the beacon. The available setting are High, Medium, Low and Ultra Low. During my testing, I didnt find any difference in the visibility range between ultra low and low. I would like to understand what are visibility range for each of the power level. Do I need to consider any other settings to improve the advertise power and visibility range? Any idea on what is the battery impact with different advertise power and its frequency? How do I decide what to settings to use and when?

void startBeacon() {

```
    if (!beaconTransmitter.isStarted()) {
        try {
            String id1 = editTextUUID.getText().toString();
            String id2 = "1";
            String id3 = "2";

            final String advertizeMode =
                    ((RadioButton) findViewById(advrtzFreqRadioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()))
                            .getText().toString();
            if (advertizeMode.equals("LOW_POWER")) {
                beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseMode(ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER);
            } else if (advertizeMode.equals("BALANCED")) {
                beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseMode(ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED);
            } else if (advertizeMode.equals("LOW_LATENCY")) {
                beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseMode(ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
            }

            final String advertizePower =
                    ((RadioButton) findViewById(advrtzPowerRadioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()))
                            .getText().toString();
            if (advertizePower.equals("ULTRA_LOW")) {
                beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_ULTRA_LOW);
            } else if (advertizePower.equals("LOW")) {
                beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_LOW);
            } else if (advertizePower.equals("MEDIUM")) {
                beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_MEDIUM);
            } else if (advertizePower.equals("HIGH")) {
                beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH);
            }

            int transmissionPower = Integer.parseInt(editTextTxPower.getText().toString());
            beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                    .setId1(id1)
                    .setId2(id2)
                    .setId3(id3)
                    .setManufacturer(0x0118)
                    .setTxPower(transmissionPower)
                    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))
                    .build();

            beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);

            Log.d(TAG, "startAdvertising started");

            textViewStatus.setText("startAdvertising started...");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            textViewStatus.setText("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Already dvertising");
        textViewStatus.setText("Already startAdvertising...");
    }

    button.setText("Stop Beacon");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different transmitter power settings are provided by the underlying Android OS APIs, and is not specific to the Android Beacon Library..  The actual difference between the different power levels varies significantly by device model.  On the Nexus 4, for example, the first device I used to test this API, the ultra low level was not detectable at all at any range.  I would say this ultra low setting is not advisable  for any production purpose due to this lack of reliability.

The high setting is generally similar on all devices, as it is limited by regulatory agencies to prevent radio interference at higher (illegal) power levels.  it does vary a bit based on each device's antenna, antenna placement and case, it is usually about -59 dBm at one meter.

There is no significant phone battery drain caused by advertising beacons even at full power.  The energy used is insignificant compared to other sources of drain like cell standby, the screen, or CPU activity.  The power used is so low, it is difficult to measure.  Surprising but true!

Use cases for power settings other than high are rare.  It  sometimes useful for testing.  Low power levels are also useful for limiting detection range, but this is more reliably handled with minimum RSSI thresholds on the receiving side, because leaving the transmitter at max power provides a higher signal to noise ratio and more reliable detections.  Only if you cannot control the receiver code in your use case (to add a minimum RSSI filter) should you reduce the transmitter power to limit the detection range.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. My use case requires limiting detection range and hence thought of using the ultra low power.